# How to Set User Device Name in WifiDirect? Is there any method to broadcast custom string using WiFiDirect without establishing connection?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

I am trying to **BroadCast** Long string using wifi direct. when **peer clicks** on the device I want to manipulate this string. 
So I decided to attach this string with device name but device name change code is not working.

I tried to use the reflection of [**WifiManger API**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.java). 
But this method is hidden cannot be accessed.

```
try {
    Method m = mManager.getClass().getMethod("setDeviceName", new Class[]{Channel.class, String.class, WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class});
    m.invoke(mManager, mChannel, BroadCastName, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Name change successful.");
            Log.println(Log.DEBUG,TAG, "Name change successful.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Log.d(TAG, "name change failed: " + reason);
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "No such method");
}
```

this try catch block trying to access this method and use it to set custom string BroadCastName as Device Name or Host name

I want Device's Default Name in WifiDirect to be Modified as String BroadCastName but I see no change.

Comment: why you use invocation instead of the public API? no such method is likely the `setDeviceName()`.

Comment: actually, I found this code on StackOverflow itself. My end goal is to change device name but I couldn't find any method to do so.

Comment: Here you are describe what you want to achieve? Please elaborate your question

Comment: I am trying to broadcast name of server